# SQL Recursive Query - Sum Rows with Lesser Rank

Tags: sql-server, rank

Using MS SQL - 2012
I am trying to run a SQL Query that ranks rows by product id's.  Then calculates a sum that represents the rows ranked less than or equal to it.
I set up a formula to do this and it works but is slow and resource expensive.

My gut feeling is there is a CTE or Rank function that would do what I want - I just don't know about it.

If a product has 4 rows, using the rank I could then recalculate a sum of lesser rows Qty's.

```
Product   Order     Qty Rank    Sum  
Apple     John      5   1       5  
Apple     Josh      2   2       7  
Apple     Jacob     1   3       8  
Apple     Jennifer  1   4       9
```

Row 1 Sum is equal to (Row 1 Qty)
Row 2 Sum is equal to (Row 1 Qty , Row 2 Qty)
Row 3 Sum is equal to (Row 1 Qty , Row 2 Qty , Row 3 Qty )
Row 4 Sum is equal to (Row 1 Qty , Row 2 Qty , Row 3 Qty , Row 4 Qty )

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Josh

Comment: Your question is hard to read. Please can you format it better. Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  And show us the Query that you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding this correctly I am thinking you want this. Also this provides sample code, if the first assumptions are wrong please comment.

```
create table #apples
(product varchar(20)
,orders varchar(20)
,qty int
)

insert into #apples
values ('apple','john',1)
,('apple','john',1)
,('apple','john',1)
,('apple','john',1)
,('apple','john',1)
,('apple','josh',1)
,('apple','josh',1)
,('apple','jacob',1)
,('apple','jennifer',1)
Go

With Tots as 
(Select product,orders,sum(qty) 'Sums', RANK() OVER (partition by product ORDER BY SUM(QTY) desc,orders) 'rnk'
 from #apples
 group by product,orders)

select t1.rnk, SUM(t2.Sums)
from tots t1
    inner join Tots t2
    on t1.rnk >= t2.rnk
    group by t1.rnk
```

Comment: Thanks - i knew there was a common table expression that would work.  Just couldn't dial it in.

Answer (score 1):

For `Sql Server 2012`+:

```
select *, sum(qty) over(partition by product order by rank) as [sum]
from products
```

`Sql Server 2008`-:

```
select *, (select sum(qty) from products p2
           where p1.product = p2.product and p2.rank <= p1.rank) as [sum]
from products p1
```

Comment: Rather than a subquery, it'd be more efficient to join p2 directly. Thus: `select p1.products, p1.order, p1.qty, p1.rank, sum(p2.qty) from products p1 join products p2 on p1.product = p2.product and p2.rank <= p1.rank group by p1.products, p1.order, p1.qty, p1.rank`